# Custom post type AND custom taxonomy are not connected

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have CPT and Taxonomy (code below). When viewing taxonomy term archive page, it's empty. WordPress doesn't know it has include my custom post type to WP_Query. Am I doing something wrong?

```
function register_cpt() {

    // POST TYPE
    $args = array(
        'label'               => 'Photogallery',
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor',),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => false,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'taxonomies'                    => array('gallery_cat')
    );
    register_post_type( 'photogallery', $args );

    // TAXONOMY
    $args = array(
        'label'                     => 'Photogallery categories',
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => false,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'gallery_cat', 'photogallery', $args );

    // CONNECTING ...
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'gallery_cat', 'photogallery' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt');
```

When visiting **example.com/gallery_cat/cat-1**, it's empty. But there is one item with this term in back-end.

When I check main query, its SQL is this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (12) )
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') //     !!!!!!!
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_author = 1
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

As clearly seen, my custom post type "photogallery" is not included.

**What am I doing wrong?** Is there some misconfiguration in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when registering the post type , try `'exclude_from_search' => false,`

Comment: Oh god! Now I see [the notice](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#exclude_from_search)... but why, WordPress, why??? Thank you, Abad!

Comment: Thanks for this. Was scratching my head for ages before I found this solution. Problem is my client doesn't want the CPT to show up in search but they DO want it to have a custom tax. I guess I'll have to `pre_get_posts` to solve that one... Just one of WP's many annoying quirks.